# Need help setting UISwitch in custom cell (XIB, Swift 4, Xcode 9)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiswitch

**Successes so far:** I have a remote data source. Data gets pulled dynamically into a View Controller. The data is used to name a .title and .subtitle on each of the reusable custom cells. Also, each custom cell has a UISwitch, which I have been able to get functional for sending out both a “subscribe” signal for push notifications (for a given group identified by the cell’s title/subtitle) and an “unsubscribe” signal as well.

**My one remaining issue:** Whenever the user "revisits" the settings VC, while my code is "resetting" the UISwitches, it causes the following warnings in Xcode 9.2:

- UISwitch.on must be used from main thread
- UISwitch.setOn(_:animated:) must be used from main thread only
- -[UISwitch setOn:animated:notifyingVisualElement:] must be used from main thread

The code below "works" -- however the desired result happens rather slowly (the UISwitches that are indeed supposed to be "on" take a good while to finally flip to "on").

**More details:**
What is needed: Whenever the VC is either shown or "re-shown," I need to "reset" the custom cell’s UISwitch to "on" if the user is subscribed to the given group, and to "off" if the user is not subscribed. Ideally, each time the VC is displayed, something should reach out and touch the OneSignal server and find out that user’s “subscribe state” for each group, using the *OneSignal.getTags()* function. I have that part working. This code is in the VC. But I need to do it the right way, to suit proper protocols regarding threading.

- VC file, “ViewController_13_Settings.swift” holds a Table View with the reusable custom cell.
- Table View file is named "CustomTableViewCell.swift"
- The custom cell is called "customCell" (I know, my names are all really creative).

**The custom cell (designed in XIB) has only three items inside it:**

1. Title – A displayed “friendly name” of a “group” to be subscribed to or unsubscribed from. Set from the remote data source
2. Subtitle – A hidden “database name” of the aforementioned group. Hidden from the user. Set from the remote data source.
3. UISwitch - named "switchMinistryGroupList"

How do I properly set the UISwitch programmatically?

**Here is the code in ViewController_13_Settings.swift that seems pertinent:**

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // set cell's title and subtitle
    cell.textLabelMinistryGroupList?.text = MinistryGroupArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textHiddenUserTagName?.text = OneSignalUserTagArray[indexPath.row]

    // set the custom cell's UISwitch.
    OneSignal.getTags({ tags in
        print("tags - \(tags!)")
        self.OneSignalUserTags = String(describing: tags)
        print("OneSignalUserTags, from within the OneSignal func, = \(self.OneSignalUserTags)")

        if self.OneSignalUserTags.range(of: cell.textHiddenUserTagName.text!) != nil {
            print("The \(cell.textHiddenUserTagName.text!) UserTag exists for this device.")
            cell.switchMinistryGroupList.isOn = true
        } else {
            cell.switchMinistryGroupList.isOn = false
        }
    }, onFailure: { error in
        print("Error getting tags - \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        // errorWithDomain - OneSignalError
        // code - HTTP error code from the OneSignal server
        // userInfo - JSON OneSignal responded with
    })
    viewWillAppear(true)
    return cell
    }
    }
```

In the above portion of the VC code, this part (below) is what is functioning but apparently not in a way the uses threading properly:

```
    if OneSignalUserTags.range(of: cell.textHiddenUserTagName.text!) != nil {
        print("The \(cell.textHiddenUserTagName.text!) UserTag exists for this device.")
        cell.switchMinistryGroupList.isOn = true
    } else {
        cell.switchMinistryGroupList.isOn = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your code is doing, but there seems to be a few things that need sorting out, that will help you solve your problem.

1) Improve the naming of your objects. This helps others see what's going on when asking questions.

Don't call your cell `CustomTableViewCell` - call it, say, `MinistryCell` or something that represents the data its displaying. Rather than `textLabelMinistryGroupList` and `textHiddenUserTagName` tree `ministryGroup` and `userTagName` etc.

2) Let the cell populate itself. Make your `IBOutlets` in your cell `private` so you can't assign to them directly in your view controller. This is a bad habit!

3) Create an object (`Ministry`, say) that corresponds to the data you're assigning to the cell. Assign this to the cell and let the cell assign to its Outlets.

4) *Never* call `viewWillAppear`, or anything like it! These are called by the system.

You'll end up with something like this:

**In your view controller**

```
struct Ministry {
    let group: String
    let userTag: String
    var tagExists: Bool?
}
```

You should create an array `var ministries: [Ministry]` and populate it at the start, rather than dealing with `MinistryGroupArray` and `OneSignalUserTagArray` separately.

**In your cell**

```
class MinistryCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var ministryGroup: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var userTagName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var switch: UISwitch!

    var ministry: Ministry? {
        didSet {
            ministryGroup.text = ministry?.group
            userTagName.text = ministry?.userTag
            if let tagExists = ministry?.tagExists {
               switch.isEnabled = false
               switch.isOn = tagExists
            } else {
               // We don't know the current state - disable the switch?
               switch.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Then you dataSource method will look like…**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! MinistryCell

    let ministry = ministries[indexPath.row]
    cell.ministry = ministry

    if ministry.tagExists == nil {
        OneSignal.getTags { tags in

        // Success - so update the corresponding ministry.tagExists
        // then reload the cell at this indexPath

        }, onFailure: { error in
            print("Error")
        })
    }    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you! While you were posting your answer, I was editing my question to try to make it more clear, and to fix the fact that some of the code was not functioning simply because I had moved it outside the OneSignal.getTags function. I will study your answer carefully and report back. In the meantime I hope my revised question makes a bit more sense. More soon.

Comment: Just for clarity sake, when you wrote, 

"In your view controller...
 
`        (at) IBOutlet private weak var ministryGroup: UILabel!
        (at) IBOutlet private weak var userTagName: UILabel!
        (at) IBOutlet private weak var switch: UISwitch!`

Those items were ones I had previously "control-dragged" to connect them to the Table View (swift) file associated with the XIB, but you're saying they should be "control-dragged" to connect them to the main VC's swift file, right?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, that should be in your table view cell subclass. You can control drag from the cell in the storyboard to your cell's class

Comment: Thanks again! I voted up your answer, although I'm new & my reputation score is too low for my vote to show. Your answers & code have introduced me to several concepts new to me & have resulted in much reading, many hours of trying out different code configurations, & great progress. After much effort I'm still stymied by a couple things. 1) although on first view the cells' switches show correct, on any revisit they all show as off -- and reloadData() in ViewWillAppear is not helping 2) I have protocol w delegate working but I'm still getting "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only."

Comment: Update: I had gone back to your answer again and again, but after much learning and many mistakes and some successes, I went back one more time to check, and found I had tried something else (while flailing about) and when I reset the specific wording to match your answer, the issue of switches not being set on revisit, went away! I'm very happy to have success on that. The warning about the main thread is in purple and seems to now be merely a menace. My app is working as intended! Thank you so much!

Comment: Another update. The success with the switches keeping their proper state is not lasting. While tooling around to visit other view controllers before returning, and then revisiting the VC with the ministryCell UISwitches, they had again lost their .isOn state and are all shown as Off. Sigh.

Comment: It's "hit or miss" now, with the switches being accurately "set" about 9 out of 10 revisits.

Comment: Congratulations on learning something new! I'd suggest you ask a new question about the switch state with the code you have working so far

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help. I will watch the situation with the switches and their state, and may indeed post another question. Thank you again!